# Only echo if user is admin PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication, content-management-system

I'm currently trying to learn PHP, which is difficult. I'm trying to make my own login system (CMS), however I'm encountering some problems during this process. I have been able to create a login script which is working for now, it's not a safe script I know, but it's just for me to learn the process.

I have added in phpmyadmin a new row which indicates what role the user have (1 or 2), 1 is user and 2 is admin. However I have no idea where to start. I assume it should be something like: if user == however I don't know how to start. Could someone help me a little bit?

I want to create something like the:

**Normal user:**
- Home
- Invoices
- Contact

**Admin:**
- Home
- Invoices
- admin
- Contact

My script so far:

```
        <?php
    session_start();
    // Verbinding maken met database
    require("db.php");

    // Functions na klikken 'inloggen'

    if (isset($_POST["login"])){ 
        $gebruikersnaam = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gebruikersnaam']);
        $wachtwoord = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['wachtwoord']);
        $selecteergebruiker = "SELECT * FROM gebruikers WHERE username ='$gebruikersnaam' AND password = '$wachtwoord'";
        $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $selecteergebruiker);
        $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
        if($check_user>0){
            header('location: home.php');
        } else { 
        echo "Onjuist!";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some hint you can start with....

```
if($check_user>0){
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($selecteergebruiker))
      { 
         session_start();
         if($row['role']==1)//user is admin
         { 
           $_SESSION['role']='Admin';
         }
         else
         {
           $_SESSION['role']='User';
         }
      }
       header('location: home.php');
        } else { 
   echo "Onjuist!";
   }
```

Now in other page you can use $_SESSION['role']; thats it..

Comment: The role would be an element in $selecteergebruiker[0]: $selecteergebruiker[0]['role']. And yes, you could do 
`if($selecteergebruiker[0]['role']==2){
    echo('You're an admin');
} else {
    echo('You're a user');
}
But I'd suggest using 0 for regular users and 1 for admins. Then you could treat $selecteergebruiker[0]['role']  like a Boolean and do crazy things, like: 
`echo($selecteergebruiker[0]['role'] ? "You're an admin" : "You're a user");`

Comment: @Werner here $selecteergebruiker was assumed to be of type mysqli_result type... and in the QA's code was $query string holder so you cant use $selecteergebruiker[0]['role']

Comment: thats fine... :) @Werner

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to the sql table called role
Set admin role to admin and other users touser than check what's the user role with an if statement

```
if ( $user['role'] == admin ) {
     Echo "Hello admin";
} else { 
     Echo "Hi user....";
}
```

Comment: *I have added in phpmyadmin a new row which indicates what role the user have (1 or 2), 1 is user and 2 is admin. However I have no idea where to start. I assume it should be something like: if user == however I don't know how to start. Could someone help me a little bit?*

Comment: Oh okay here's what to do first set admin to 1 and user to 0 ( boolean )

Comment: Secondly output user informations inside an array ( i recommend using mysqli prepared statement) than check the role

Comment: If ($info['role']) { echo 'admin'; } else { echo 'user'; }

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42189008/php-mysqli-im-trying-to-output-data-but-i-keep-getting-empty-array/42189931#42189931

Comment: i was trying this 

```if ( $user['role'] == 1) {
     Echo "Hello admin";
} else { 
     Echo "Hi user....";
}```

how to mention role 1 = admin , and 2 = user